# running winzip on a remote machine

Tags: compression

I have a remote server that i want to unzip some file onto:

At first, I ran Winzip to unzip on my local machine and then copied it to the remote server but that copy action was very slow

I then copied over the zip file to the remote server and ran unzip through there but surprisingly the unzipping took forever.  My guess is that even though the files are already on the server and getting unzipped locally, that winzip doesn't realize this and is somehow using my local machine as a temp stage before unzipping to the remote directory.

Is there anyway to unzip on a remote machine to that same remote machine and have it work as fast as if I were logged in locally to that machine?

Answer (score 4):

The way you did it was that your local machine was doing the actual unzipping, just against data that was remote - what you need to do is run the unzip code on the remote server via something like RDP/VNC/SSH or similar - you need full access to the remote machine via one of these protocols first though ok.